# Smallest gaps between powers of 2 and 3

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find the smallest gaps between powers of 2 and 3.

Such examples are: (2, 3) (3, 4) (8, 9) (27, 32) (243, 256) (2048, 2187) (16384, 19683) (524288, 531441)... What are the next smallest gaps possible?

With gaps of 1, 1, 1, 5, 13, 139, 3299, 7133?

I would have checked to see if there is an Oeis sequence for this and there appears to be none.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Is it obvious there can't be a gap of size 7?

Comment: @user7530 you mean $2^4-3^2$. Note also $3^3-2^4=11$.

Comment: @almagest Hah, right. So clearly the OP's list is missing some entries. Is it known if $2^a-3^b=n$ has a solution for all $n$ relatively prime to $2$ and $3$?

Comment: 7 isn't the smallest possible gap in that case since 2^5-3^3 is 5, a smaller gap for a larger range. 2^7-3^4 = 47 wouldn't count either since 2^8-3^5 = 13, a smaller gap, for another larger range.

Comment: @T.Rex Can you edit into the question a formal statement of what you mean by a "gap for a larger range"? I don't follow.

Comment: (2^x-3^y or 3^y-2^x) > (3^b-2^a or 2^a-3^b) where x <= a, y <= b.

Comment: @T.Rex Here's a reference to Mathjax commands, use it next time. :)
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pari/GP gives the following "addition-table" where the entries $d_{r,c}=|2^r - 3^c|$ are shown, with *r* the row-index and *c* the column-index:

```
   d|      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10      11      12
 ---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1|      1      7     25     79    241    727   2185   6559  19681  59047  177145  531439
   2|      1      5     23     77    239    725   2183   6557  19679  59045  177143  531437
   3|      5      1     19     73    235    721   2179   6553  19675  59041  177139  531433
   4|     13      7     11     65    227    713   2171   6545  19667  59033  177131  531425
   5|     29     23      5     49    211    697   2155   6529  19651  59017  177115  531409
   6|     61     55     37     17    179    665   2123   6497  19619  58985  177083  531377
   7|    125    119    101     47    115    601   2059   6433  19555  58921  177019  531313
   8|    253    247    229    175     13    473   1931   6305  19427  58793  176891  531185
   9|    509    503    485    431    269    217   1675   6049  19171  58537  176635  530929
  10|   1021   1015    997    943    781    295   1163   5537  18659  58025  176123  530417
  11|   2045   2039   2021   1967   1805   1319    139   4513  17635  57001  175099  529393
  12|   4093   4087   4069   4015   3853   3367   1909   2465  15587  54953  173051  527345
  13|   8189   8183   8165   8111   7949   7463   6005   1631  11491  50857  168955  523249
  14|  16381  16375  16357  16303  16141  15655  14197   9823   3299  42665  160763  515057
  15|  32765  32759  32741  32687  32525  32039  30581  26207  13085  26281  144379  498673
  16|  65533  65527  65509  65455  65293  64807  63349  58975  45853   6487  111611  465905
```

In general, the entries are growing with growing row- and column-indexes, and "very exceptional" cases should not occur due to the knowledge of linear forms of logarithms (I don't know much about this, you need to look in related books)

---

Also perhaps this discussion of mine might be interesting for you; however I was not focusing the absolute values of distances, but distances relative to the exponent *l* at the basis *3* and only where $2^k>3^l$ , see [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the table. I wanted to know the smallest value in each row or column.

Comment: The row/col-minima follow roughly the main diagonal; exactly its tangent depends on the ratio log(3)/log(2) and should roughly be $r/c \approx 1.59$

Answer (score 0):

By the Mihăilescu-Catalan theorem (but for sure this particular case has an elementary solution)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture

you'll never get $2^k-3^l=1$ with $k,l>1$ and the only case when  $3^k-2^l=1$ for $k,l>1$ is $3^2-2^3$.

Hence $3-2$, $4-3$, $9-8$ are the only cases when you get 1 as a difference.

---

Big differences seem to cause a highly nontrivial problem. See

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116840/distance-between-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3